# How to customize the \textcite command?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I use Biblatex with the authoryear-icomp citation style. The `\textcite{ref}` command prints out Lastname (year) ie Groenig (2000) but I want it to give me Firstname Lastname (year) ie Peter Groenig (2000).

As you can see, this customization does not only involve formatting but also retrieving new informations from the `.bib` file. I want all others citation commands, such as `\parencite`, to keep their original behaviour.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `authoryear-icomp` we need to modify the bibmacro `textcite` to use the name format `first-last` instead of the `labelname` format, we can do this either by redefining the entire macro

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                    \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
          {\setunit{\addcomma}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
       {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
        \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{%
             \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
             \addspace\bibopenparen}%
           \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
             {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
             {}%
           \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
       {\printnames[first-last]{labelname}%<----- this is the modification
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \addspace\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
           \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}
\makeatother
```

Or using the [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package as follows

```
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
  {\printnames{labelname}}
  {\printnames[first-last]{labelname}}
  {}
  {}
```

MWE (using `xpatch`)

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,backend=biber]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
  {\printnames{labelname}}
  {\printnames[first-last]{labelname}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{geer} ipsum \textcite{worman} dolor \textcite{sigfridsson}.

Lorem \cite{geer} ipsum \cite{worman} dolor \cite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

This modification cannot be adopted wholesale to all other styles, because `\textcite` unlike other commands is implemented using a variety of different ways. The basic idea of making the `\printnames{labelname}` directive use the `first-last` name format, however, should almost always be the right one.