# Sort authors and organizations alphabetically

Tags: biblatex

The alphabetical sorting doesn't work if I have entries with only an organization. The bibliography should be sorted alphabetically in a non-hierachical way between the organization and the author.

I don't think that the solution with corporate authors in double brackets works, because I need the organizations in italics.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
      @online{musk,
        author       = {Elon Musk},
        title        = {Tesla Model X},
        url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
        date         = {2017-07-04},
        organization = {Tesla},
        urldate      = {2018-10-16},
      },
    
 @online{b,
    title        = {Tesla Model X},
    url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
    date         = {2017-07-04},
    organization = {ABZ},
    urldate      = {2018-10-16},
},

 @online{a,
    title        = {Tesla Model X},
    url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
    date         = {2017-07-04},
    organization = {ZBA},
    urldate      = {2018-10-16},
},
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareListFormat{organization}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  \mkbibemph{#1}\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! \footcite{musk} \footcite{a} \footcite{b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With this MWE I get the following output: [image]

However, it should be sorted as follows:

ABZ [...]
Musk [...]
ZBA [...]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The customization for the organisation comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464166/biblatex-move-organization

Comment: If you have bib entries without an `author` field but with an `organization` field, you may want to rethink the organization (pun intended) of these entries: change the name of the `organization` field to `author` and encase the `author `field in double curly braces. That way, you inform biblatex (or BibTeX) that it's dealing with a "corporate" author, not the name of a "normal" person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the `organization` field is not part of the default sort template. You could either add it or, as I suggest you assuming you have a limited number of such entries, you can provide a `sortkey` to the bib entries of interest:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @online{musk,
    author       = {Elon Musk},
    title        = {Tesla Model X},
    url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
    date         = {2017-07-04},
    organization = {Tesla},
    urldate      = {2018-10-16},
  },

  @online{b,
    title        = {Tesla Model X},
    url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
    date         = {2017-07-04},
    organization = {ABZ},
    sortkey      = {ABZ},
    urldate      = {2018-10-16},
  },

  @online{a,
    title        = {Tesla Model X},
    url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
    date         = {2017-07-04},
    organization = {ZBA},
    sortkey      = {ZBA},
    urldate      = {2018-10-16},
  },
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareListFormat{organization}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  \mkbibemph{#1}\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
  {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
  {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! \footcite{musk} \footcite{a} \footcite{b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, as requested in the comments, by adding `organization` to the sorting template:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @online{musk,
    author       = {Elon Musk},
    title        = {Tesla Model X},
    url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
    date         = {2017-07-04},
    organization = {Tesla},
    urldate      = {2018-10-16},
  },

  @online{b,
    title        = {Tesla Model X},
    url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
    date         = {2017-07-04},
    organization = {ABZ},
    urldate      = {2018-10-16},
  },

  @online{a,
    title        = {Tesla Model X},
    url          = {https://www.tesla.com/modelx?redirect=no},
    date         = {2017-07-04},
    organization = {ZBA},
    urldate      = {2018-10-16},
  },
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nty}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{organization}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\DeclareListFormat{organization}{%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  \mkbibemph{#1}\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
  {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
  {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}
  {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! \footcite{musk} \footcite{a} \footcite{b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed I have quite some entries without an author. How difficult is it to add the organization to the sort template?

Comment: @derd See edit.