# footnote goes over margin

Tags: footnotes

The second line of the footnote goes over the left margin. [image]

How can I achieve that the second line is in a line with the first line?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{incollection,
    author       = {Peter Farindon}, 
    title        = {The title of the work},
    booktitle    = {The title of the book},
    publisher    = {The name of the publisher},
    year         = 1993,
    pages     ={10},
}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    Let's cite!  \footcite{incollection} 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467022/customize-second-citation-for-books-articles-incollection

Comment: No, the question I asked there was about another issue then the answer given. However, I found it interesting so I posted a new question.

Comment: So it is related. You already have the answer and are just waiting for Markus to post it here. So people don't have to work on this question, as the work is already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the layout of the footnote with the following code added to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}% <===================================
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
%   \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.2\textwidth}%
    \footnotesize}%
  \item[\@makefnmark\hfil]#1%
  \end{list}%
}
\makeatother
```

The command `\setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}` defines the length given to the foornote number you can change for your needs ...

The complete code

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{incollection,
    author       = {Peter Farindon}, 
    title        = {The title of the work},
    booktitle    = {The title of the book},
    publisher    = {The name of the publisher},
    year         = 1993,
    pages     ={10},
}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}% <===================================
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
%   \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.2\textwidth}%
    \footnotesize}%
  \item[\@makefnmark\hfil]#1%
  \end{list}%
}
\makeatother


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    Let's cite!  \footcite{incollection} 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives you the result:

[image]

If you do not want the second line indentend on the left change `\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}` for example to `\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}` ...

Because you are writing in German please consider to use normal footnote numbers (have a look into the German Duden). To get that please add the line

```
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}
```

after `\makeatletter` ...

Then you get with the complete code

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{incollection,
    author       = {Peter Farindon}, 
    title        = {The title of the work},
    booktitle    = {The title of the book},
    publisher    = {The name of the publisher},
    year         = 1993,
    pages     ={10},
}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark}} % <==========
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}% <===================================
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
%   \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.2\textwidth}%
    \footnotesize}%
  \item[\@makefnmark\hfil]#1%
  \end{list}%
}
\makeatother


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    Let's cite!  \footcite{incollection} 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the result

[image]

Comment: How does the german footnote differ from the standard footnote?

Comment: @heidil The footnote number in the footnote is not superscripted, it is in normal font size and the footnote uses an hanging format, that means the text of the footnote is set justified. Please see the red arrow in the last image ...

Comment: Funny, I didn't know that there's a difference between german footnote and the standard. I tried your code out, but now there is a huge gap between the foonotes and I cannot imagine that this is the german standard. But probably it would be a good idea to open a new question just on german footnotes. What do you think?

Comment: @heidil Please ask a new question, show the code you used and show us a screenshot with the gap. Then we can help you ...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the package [footmisc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc?lang=en) package

```
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
```

There are two options `flushmargin`and `hang`

> flushmargin
>
> This option is as option marginal, but sets the footnote marker flush with, but
>   just inside the margin from, the text of the footnote.

and

> hang
>
> This option sets the footnote mark flush with the margin, and makes the body
>   of the footnote hang at an indentation of \footnotemargin (if that is a positive
>   distance), or the width of the marker (if \footnotemargin≤ 0). The option code
>   itself leaves \footnotemargin at its default value of 1.8em.
>   The footnote itself may of course be longer than one paragraph; if so, the
>   paragraphs will be separated by the vertical space specified by \hangfootparskip,
>   and the second and subsequent paragraphs are indented by \hangfootparindent.
>   Default values are:

e.g.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{article,
    author  = {Hans Zimmer},
    title   = {The title of the work The title of the work The title of the work},
    journal = {Some journal},
    year    = {2013},
    number  = {12},
    pages   = {40-41},
}


@book{book,
author    = {Peter Babington}, 
title     = {The title of the work The title of the work The title of the work The title of the work},
year      = 1993,
pages     ={310},
}


@incollection{incollection,
author       = {Peter Farindon}, 
title        = {The title of the work},
booktitle    = {The title of the book},
publisher    = {The name of the publisher},
year         = 1993,
pages     ={10},
}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc} 

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Let's cite! \footcite{ article} \footcite{incollection} \footcite{book}     \footcite{article} \footcite{incollection} \footcite{book}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which produces
[image: footnote without indent]