# Reduce spacing in German footnote style

Tags: footnotes, german

As [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467080/footnote-goes-over-margin/467087?noredirect=1#comment1177773_467087) in the accepted answer there is a difference between the standard footnote style and the German footnote style.

The code from below gives some strange space in-between two citation (as marked in red). How can I avoid that?

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{incollection,
    author       = {Peter Farindon}, 
    title        = {The title of the work},
    booktitle    = {The title of the book},
    publisher    = {The name of the publisher},
    year         = 1993,
    pages     ={10},
}

@incollection{a,
    author       = {Peter Farindon}, 
    title        = {The title of the work},
    booktitle    = {The title of the book},
    publisher    = {The name of the publisher},
    year         = 1993,
    pages     ={10},
}

@incollection{b,
    author       = {Peter Farindon}, 
    title        = {The title of the work},
    booktitle    = {The title of the book},
    publisher    = {The name of the publisher},
    year         = 1993,
    pages     ={10},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}% <===================================
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
%   \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.2\textwidth}%
    \footnotesize}%
  \item[\@makefnmark\hfil]#1%
  \end{list}%
}
\makeatother


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    Let's cite!  \footcite{incollection} \footcite{a} \footcite{b}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried playing with the `\topsep` parameter? Setting it to a negative value, eg -2pt should do the trick

Comment: In that case setting `\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}` directly is probably nicer than trying to cancel out `\partopset` with a negative `\topsep`.

Comment: I too suggested that to make "\partopsep" to 0pt, instead of changing "\topsep" as a negative value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this `list` environment is the conceptually best way to format footnotes, but since many environments are based on `\list` or `\trivlist` this is probably not too outlandish.

You will want to set the length `\partopsep` to `0` as well. See [\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep and \parsep - what does each of them mean (and what about the bottom)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300340/35864) for more on all the lengths involved.

I don't think it is necessary to set `\parindent` to zero, so I dropped that line. I also dropped the `\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}` because it would otherwise be quite challenging to make out the beginning of a new paragraph in a footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5em}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{3pt}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
    \footnotesize}%
  \item[\@makefnmark\hfil]#1%
  \end{list}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 Lorem\footnote{\kant[1]} dolor\footnote{\kant[2]\par\kant[3]} amet\footnote{\kant[4]}  amet\footnote{\kant[5]}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the MWE and its footnotes. There is no excessive space between footnotes. Paragraphs within footnotes are separated by vertical space.]