# With biblatex, do not capitalise prefixes for last names in the index

Tags: biblatex, indexing

Sending bibliographical entries to the index with `biblatex` causes capitalisation of prefixes that is sometimes unwanted. For example, Dutch names with prefix *van* or French names with prefix *de* are sometimes not capitalised in indexes. Also, maybe a little more unusual but still possibly relevant, I've recently learned about a researcher who wishes to be cited with their name in lower case only (I believe this was somewhere in SocSci).

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @misc{vanTrijp2013,
        author = {van Trijp, Remi},
        date = {2013},
        title = {A Comparison between approach A and B},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authoryear,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
    \cite{vanTrijp2013}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following entry in the `.dx` file:

```
\indexentry{van Trijp, Remi@\MakeCapital {van} Trijp, Remi}{1}
```

And this produces the index entry *Van Trijp, Remi*, although *van Trijp, Remi* would be prefered. I would like the `\MakeCapital` to be optional without confusing the sorting of entries in the index.

The issue might be related to `\mkbibindexname` from `biblatex.def`, where `\MakeCapital` is hard-coded.

A possible solution is, using `etoolbox`, to simply delete the `\MakeCapital` from the definition:

```
\patchcmd{\mkbibindexname}{\ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\MakeCapital{#3} }}{\ifdefvoid{#3}{}{#3 }}{}{}
```

But I don't think changing the code of a package this way is a sustainable solution. Do you know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the actual definition of `\mkbibindexname` looks a bit daunting, the user *is* supposed to change that macro if they don't like the output it produces. So it would be perfectly fine to patch the macro as you suggest. There is a general question of whether it is better to patch or to redefine a macro (see for example [Biblatex's bibmacros, bibliography drivers, formats - patch or redefine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409091/35864)) and for 'small' macros like `\mkbibindexname` I would usually favour the redefine route instead of patching, but that is up to personal preference.

For this application we might redefine the macro in question as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authoryear,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mkbibindexname}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\ifdefvoid{#3}{}{#3 }%
     \@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{, #2}}
    {\@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {,}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{ #2}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{ #3}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{vanTrijp2013,
  author = {van Trijp, Remi},
  date   = {2013},
  title  = {A Comparison between approach A and B},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
  \cite{vanTrijp2013}
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: van Trijp, Remi, 1]

It should also be possible to optionally apply `\MakeCapital` to a name if a certain option is set, but then you would have to decide on how you would like to tell `biblatex` about this.