# Omit 'hereafter cited as' if citation is only used once

Tags: biblatex-chicago

Is it possible to have `biblatex-chicago` not print the 'hereafter cited as X' message for entries with a shorthand if the entry is only cited once in the document?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{entry,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
shorthand = {shorthand}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum.\autocite{entry}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, this would produce a footnote that says simply 'Some Author, *Book's title*' rather than including '(hereafter cited as shorthand)', as it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we enable the `citecounter` option we can test if an entry is cited more than once and make the execution of the `cms:shorthandintro` macro, which prints the "hereafter cited as ..." phrase, conditional on there being more than one citation of this work

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citecounter=context]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cms:shorthandintro}{%
  \ifboolexpr{   test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}}
              or not test {\ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{1}}}%
    {}%
    {\iffieldundef{shorthandintro}%
       {\ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{jurisdiction}\OR\ifentrytype{legal}\OR%
                    \ifentrytype{legislation}}%
         {\printtext[brackets]{%
            \bibstring{hereinafter}\addspace%
            \printfield{shorthand}}}%
         {\printtext[parens]{%
            \bibstring{citedas}\addspace%
            \printfield{shorthand}}}}%
       {%\addspace%\setunit{\addspace}% Ditto
        \printfield{shorthandintro}}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum.\autocite{kant:kpv}

Lorem ipsum.\autocite{kant:ku}

Lorem ipsum.\autocite{kant:ku}
\end{document}
```

[image: Immanuel Kant, “Kritik der praktischen Vernunft,” in Kritik der praktischen Vernunft. Kritik der Urtheilskraft, vol. 5 of Kants Werke. Akademie Textausgabe (Berlin: Walter de Gruyter, 1968), 1–163.// Immanuel Kant, “Kritik der Urtheilskraft,” in Kritik der praktischen Vernunft. Kritik der Urtheilskraft, vol. 5 of Kants Werke. Akademie Textausgabe (Berlin: Walter de Gruyter, 1968), 165–485 (hereafter cited as KU).//KU]

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'm guessing you copied the macro definition from the `biblatex-chicago` source files; is that correct? If so, is that something to keep an eye on for maintaining this code going forward?

Comment: @AVB Yes, the code is adapted from `chicago-notes.cbx`. Of course future changes to that file might mean that the code diverges from the original more than intended. If you prefer you can patch the macro instead. That *could* be more robust. See the discussion in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409091/35864.